# Why didn't Shiva take avatars like Maha Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, avatars

I need to know that, why lord Siva has not taken any avatar like lord Vishnu?
as I am a devotee of both supreme lords (lord Siva and lord Maha Vishnu).

If anybody knows the answer , please help me.

Comment: your Q's title is asking 1 question, and body asking another. what is exactly is your question? for the point in your post, `why lord siva has not taken any avatar like lord vishnu` this is incorrect as per this link http://www.ajabgjab.com/2014/02/19-avatars-of-lord-shiva-bhagwan-shiv.html

Comment: @AADHinduism I know but we are not allowed to change the entire question against OP's will. There are avatars of Shiva too. But I would say them as amshas..

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Yes. That depends on what he mean by avatar. These 19 are not avatars like how Vishnu has avatars, shaivite says Mahadeva doesn't pass through any wombs, etc.